# TypeError: crypto.createCredentials is not a function

Tags: node.js

While authenticating with google i m getting this error:
TypeError: crypto.createCredentials is not a function
    at exports.OAuth2._request (D:\WEB_D_CODING_NINJAS\Back-end\6.major\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:33:22)
    at exports.OAuth2.getOAuthAccessToken (D:\WEB_D_CODING_NINJAS\Back-end\6.major\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:130:8)
    at loaded (D:\WEB_D_CODING_NINJAS\Back-end\6.major\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:173:20)
    at NullStore.verify (D:\WEB_D_CODING_NINJAS\Back-end\6.major\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\state\null.js:9:3)
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.authenticate (D:\WEB_D_CODING_NINJAS\Back-end\6.major\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:219:26)
    at attempt (D:\WEB_D_CODING_NINJAS\Back-end\6.major\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:366:16)
    at authenticate (D:\WEB_D_CODING_NINJAS\Back-end\6.major\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:367:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\WEB_D_CODING_NINJAS\Back-end\6.major\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\WEB_D_CODING_NINJAS\Back-end\6.major\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\WEB_D_CODING_NINJAS\Back-end\6.major\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\WEB_D_CODING_NINJAS\Back-end\6.major\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\WEB_D_CODING_NINJAS\Back-end\6.major\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (D:\WEB_D_CODING_NINJAS\Back-end\6.major\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (D:\WEB_D_CODING_NINJAS\Back-end\6.major\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (D:\WEB_D_CODING_NINJAS\Back-end\6.major\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (D:\WEB_D_CODING_NINJAS\Back-end\6.major\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)

Comment: Plz use codeblocks when pasting tracebacks

Answer (score 0):

faced this doubt myself, took a lot of effort but finally, I figured it out, this is a problem because of your file in node modules read the error and reach here

node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:33 , on line 33 you will see that crypto.createCredentails command, I don't know why this file gets installed but change the code inside it
make it this one

```js
var querystring= require('querystring'),
    crypto= require('crypto'),
    https= require('https'),
    http= require('http'),
    URL= require('url'),
    OAuthUtils= require('./_utils');

exports.OAuth2= function(clientId, clientSecret, baseSite, authorizePath, accessTokenPath, customHeaders) {
  this._clientId= clientId;
  this._clientSecret= clientSecret;
  this._baseSite= baseSite;
  this._authorizeUrl= authorizePath || "/oauth/authorize";
  this._accessTokenUrl= accessTokenPath || "/oauth/access_token";
  this._accessTokenName= "access_token";
  this._authMethod= "Bearer";
  this._customHeaders = customHeaders || {};
  this._useAuthorizationHeaderForGET= false;

  //our agent
  this._agent = undefined;
};

// Allows you to set an agent to use instead of the default HTTP or
// HTTPS agents. Useful when dealing with your own certificates.
exports.OAuth2.prototype.setAgent = function(agent) {
  this._agent = agent;
};

// This 'hack' method is required for sites that don't use
// 'access_token' as the name of the access token (for requests).
// ( http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-16#section-7 )
// it isn't clear what the correct value should be atm, so allowing
// for specific (temporary?) override for now.
exports.OAuth2.prototype.setAccessTokenName= function ( name ) {
  this._accessTokenName= name;
}

// Sets the authorization method for Authorization header.
// e.g. Authorization: Bearer <token>  # "Bearer" is the authorization method.
exports.OAuth2.prototype.setAuthMethod = function ( authMethod ) {
  this._authMethod = authMethod;
};


// If you use the OAuth2 exposed 'get' method (and don't construct your own _request call )
// this will specify whether to use an 'Authorize' header instead of passing the access_token as a query parameter
exports.OAuth2.prototype.useAuthorizationHeaderforGET = function(useIt) {
  this._useAuthorizationHeaderForGET= useIt;
}

exports.OAuth2.prototype._getAccessTokenUrl= function() {
  return this._baseSite + this._accessTokenUrl; /* + "?" + querystring.stringify(params); */
}

// Build the authorization header. In particular, build the part after the colon.
// e.g. Authorization: Bearer <token>  # Build "Bearer <token>"
exports.OAuth2.prototype.buildAuthHeader= function(token) {
  return this._authMethod + ' ' + token;
};

exports.OAuth2.prototype._chooseHttpLibrary= function( parsedUrl ) {
  var http_library= https;
  // As this is OAUth2, we *assume* https unless told explicitly otherwise.
  if( parsedUrl.protocol != "https:" ) {
    http_library= http;
  }
  return http_library;
};

exports.OAuth2.prototype._request= function(method, url, headers, post_body, access_token, callback) {

  var parsedUrl= URL.parse( url, true );
  if( parsedUrl.protocol == "https:" && !parsedUrl.port ) {
    parsedUrl.port= 443;
  }

  var http_library= this._chooseHttpLibrary( parsedUrl );


  var realHeaders= {};
  for( var key in this._customHeaders ) {
    realHeaders[key]= this._customHeaders[key];
  }
  if( headers ) {
    for(var key in headers) {
      realHeaders[key] = headers[key];
    }
  }
  realHeaders['Host']= parsedUrl.host;

  if (!realHeaders['User-Agent']) {
    realHeaders['User-Agent'] = 'Node-oauth';
  }

  if( post_body ) {
      if ( Buffer.isBuffer(post_body) ) {
          realHeaders["Content-Length"]= post_body.length;
      } else {
          realHeaders["Content-Length"]= Buffer.byteLength(post_body);
      }
  } else {
      realHeaders["Content-length"]= 0;
  }

  if( access_token && !('Authorization' in realHeaders)) {
    if( ! parsedUrl.query ) parsedUrl.query= {};
    parsedUrl.query[this._accessTokenName]= access_token;
  }

  var queryStr= querystring.stringify(parsedUrl.query);
  if( queryStr ) queryStr=  "?" + queryStr;
  var options = {
    host:parsedUrl.hostname,
    port: parsedUrl.port,
    path: parsedUrl.pathname + queryStr,
    method: method,
    headers: realHeaders
  };

  this._executeRequest( http_library, options, post_body, callback );
}

exports.OAuth2.prototype._executeRequest= function( http_library, options, post_body, callback ) {
  // Some hosts *cough* google appear to close the connection early / send no content-length header
  // allow this behaviour.
  var allowEarlyClose= OAuthUtils.isAnEarlyCloseHost(options.host);
  var callbackCalled= false;
  function passBackControl( response, result ) {
    if(!callbackCalled) {
      callbackCalled=true;
      if( !(response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode <= 299) && (response.statusCode != 301) && (response.statusCode != 302) ) {
        callback({ statusCode: response.statusCode, data: result });
      } else {
        callback(null, result, response);
      }
    }
  }

  var result= "";

  //set the agent on the request options
  if (this._agent) {
    options.agent = this._agent;
  }

  var request = http_library.request(options);
  request.on('response', function (response) {
    response.on("data", function (chunk) {
      result+= chunk
    });
    response.on("close", function (err) {
      if( allowEarlyClose ) {
        passBackControl( response, result );
      }
    });
    response.addListener("end", function () {
      passBackControl( response, result );
    });
  });
  request.on('error', function(e) {
    callbackCalled= true;
    callback(e);
  });

  if( (options.method == 'POST' || options.method == 'PUT') && post_body ) {
     request.write(post_body);
  }
  request.end();
}

exports.OAuth2.prototype.getAuthorizeUrl= function( params ) {
  var params= params || {};
  params['client_id'] = this._clientId;
  return this._baseSite + this._authorizeUrl + "?" + querystring.stringify(params);
}

exports.OAuth2.prototype.getOAuthAccessToken= function(code, params, callback) {
  var params= params || {};
  params['client_id'] = this._clientId;
  params['client_secret'] = this._clientSecret;
  var codeParam = (params.grant_type === 'refresh_token') ? 'refresh_token' : 'code';
  params[codeParam]= code;

  var post_data= querystring.stringify( params );
  var post_headers= {
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   };


  this._request("POST", this._getAccessTokenUrl(), post_headers, post_data, null, function(error, data, response) {
    if( error )  callback(error);
    else {
      var results;
      try {
        // As of http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-07
        // responses should be in JSON
        results= JSON.parse( data );
      }
      catch(e) {
        // .... However both Facebook + Github currently use rev05 of the spec
        // and neither seem to specify a content-type correctly in their response headers :(
        // clients of these services will suffer a *minor* performance cost of the exception
        // being thrown
        results= querystring.parse( data );
      }
      var access_token= results["access_token"];
      var refresh_token= results["refresh_token"];
      delete results["refresh_token"];
      callback(null, access_token, refresh_token, results); // callback results =-=
    }
  });
}

// Deprecated
exports.OAuth2.prototype.getProtectedResource= function(url, access_token, callback) {
  this._request("GET", url, {}, "", access_token, callback );
}

exports.OAuth2.prototype.get= function(url, access_token, callback) {
  if( this._useAuthorizationHeaderForGET ) {
    var headers= {'Authorization': this.buildAuthHeader(access_token) }
    access_token= null;
  }
  else {
    headers= {};
  }
  this._request("GET", url, headers, "", access_token, callback );
}
```

after changing this file, google OAuth will work just fine